# Show string in object

Tags: javascript, object

There is a model like this `console.log(model);` :

```
      Class {modified: Object, raw: Object, stores: Array[2], data: Object, _data...
```

In data of this model you see with `console.log(model.getData("timestamp"));`  :

```
      Object {person: "", Id: "1234", timestamp: "1418817456590", description: "blabla"...
```

I cannot see the timestamp with the last call...

I also tried `console.log(model.data.timestamp);` and `console.log(model.get("timestamp"));`. There you get 0.0 as a result

How can I see the timestamp?

Comment: Do you mean `model.getData()` gives you the second log rather than `model.getData("timestamp")`? In which case `model.getData().timestamp` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've provided (that `model.getData("timestamp")` returns a JavaScript object), you should be able to use:

```
model.getData("timestamp").timestamp;
```

Comment: @kadddah when you call `model.getData("timestamp")` you get that object (`Object {person: "", Id: "1234", ...`)?

Comment: yes.
I see there is another problem. when I call it first the 0.0 appears. If I call it directly after that, the right timestamp appears...???

Comment: @kadddah sounds like your `model` isn't fully initiated when you first log the values it holds. If it's being populated through an AJAX call I suggest implementing a callback function.

Comment: ok I found an error but it was waaaay too long away from this section. It was in the database code...
but thank you for your help. I think I can use the idea with the callback in other sections of my project :)